# Can I convince EPA encrypt for an expired key

Tags: encryption, epa

Through a series of my own errors my public key is expired and I don't have the master key with me to re-sign it. I use this key to encrypt many files i use on a daily basis, most importantly org files in emacs.

Can I convince EPA to encrypt for the expired key anyway even though it's expired?

my org file starts with

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("B66NNNNNNNNNNN3EA") -*-
```

does it take additional options or can I change other things in gpg to make it trusted, provided i have only the encryption and signing (non-master) keys with me?

Answer (score 1):

Set the time on your computer to last year ? I guess any year after 1970 can be set , though individual hardware, software, interfaces would add restrictions.